# Point a domain name to elasticbeanstalk url aws

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, networking, subdomain

I have a domain name owned by my company with url xyz.com, I want to point this to a elasticbeanstalk url in AWS.

My company provides domain name pointing as A record & CNAME, till now whatever I pointed to company domain name was an IP address and I selected A record it worked fine, but now when I select A record for elasticbeanstalk url it doesnt points correctly

xyz.com --> elasticbeanstalk-uri

What should I do in order to point my domain name to elasticbeanstalk url running wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You should obtain the domain name of your load balancer and add it as a CNAME 
This way you avoid providing an IP address that might change.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html#dns-associate-custom-elb

From the docs:

If you'd prefer to use a friendly DNS name for your load balancer, such as www.example.com, instead of the default DNS name, you can create a custom domain name and associate it with the DNS name for your load balancer. When a client makes a request using this custom domain name, the DNS server resolves it to the DNS name for your load balancer

Comment: You can, but then you would effectively bypassing yr load balancer.you should NOT use the public ip though which can change. Also i think you need a CNAME and not an A record.

Comment: Isn't it the case that requests first comes to elasticbeanstalk url then goes to load balancer ? Also will elasticbean url address change anytime ? If i dont change it explictly

Comment: No they first go to ELB. It won't change if you don't recreate the environment. The public ip of the ec2 instance can change though. The main function of the ELB is to distribute the load among the ec2 instances.

Comment: Then if I point to the elasticbeanstalk url or the CNAME that is generated that would be ok ? anyways if I recreate the environment loadbalancer will also be changed.

Comment: Yes. The CNAME should be www.yourdomain.com pointing to awseb-e-p-AWSEBLoa-203303123-32023.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. You can use either the DNS name of the load balancer like the example above or the elastic bean stalk DNS name. But if you have a load balancer use it. And yes if you recreate the environment the loadbalancer DNS name will also change.